# String has unicode code points embedded, how to convert? Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

This string is coming from the 3rd party module:

> /var/www/atenci\xc3\xb3n+integral+a+las+personas+con+c\xc3\xa1ncer

if you prepend it with b'' and decode from utf-8 the output is correct:

```
path = b'/var/www/atenci\xc3\xb3n+integral+a+las+personas+con+c\xc3\xa1ncer'
print(path.decode('utf-8'))
```

> /var/www/atención+integral+a+las+personas+con+cáncer

but if I try encode and decode it right away with built in functions or io.BytesIO the output is broken:

```
path = '/var/www/atenci\xc3\xb3n+integral+a+las+personas+con+c\xc3\xa1ncer'
decoded = path.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
print(decoded)
```

> /var/www/atenciÃ³n+integral+a+las+personas+con+cÃ¡ncer

So, is there any way to make it work like prepending with b'' ?

Comment: Yes, just do nothing. Python will resolve `\x` internally. If you have string `'/var/www/atenci\\xc3\\xb3n+integral+a+las+personas+con+c\\xc3\\xa1ncer'` then use `path.encode().decode('unicode_escape')`

Comment: Don't put UTF-8 sequences in a `str` value.

Comment: I consider it a bit of a wart that you can use `\x` at all to specify Unicode code points in a `str` value. That's what `\u` is for; `\x` should probably be considered a syntax error.

Comment: As mentioned above I have no control of the incoming string, and if you look up the the unicode table the point '\xc3\xb3' translates to correct ó

Comment: A common hack is to encode it into Latin-1 (which has the attractive and unique property that every code point is encoded as a byte with that value) and then decode as UTF-8. In some way, this could be regarded as "reverse [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)". This is probably a duplicate of an existing question, as such.